# MySQLi extension is missing

Tags: php, mysqli

I know thousands of other people have asked this before me but I already read about 4 other questions and their replies mostly said to remove the semicolon (I am using Windows, by the way) from the ";extension = mysqli" and stop MySQL before trying again. Although I never had the semicolon in the first place, I tried anyways. Then I read I had to specify the "ext" folder path in "extension_dir =", but it was set already. I also tried replacing it with "extension = php_mysqli.dll". At this point I have no idea on what I should do.
Here is my php.ini file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ECmee20GyKQbKdAicedpgpiMzGhNduAI/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you have the `php_mysqli.dll` file in the `ext` folder inside your PHP installation directory?

Comment: there are many answers, not one. you need to make sure you are editing the correct php ini file. you need to restart the web server after editing php ini etc.

Comment: @ManSamVampire I have it, I just double checked. It just won't work though

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am editing the php.ini located in "...\xampp\php" and it still shows that up and always stop MySQL before trying again. I know I am missing something little, I just can't quite figure out what.

Comment: in case your PHP is not standalone but a part of some software bundle, you are supposed to use this bundle's control panel or something

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'll keep looking then. Thank you